# Is there any API For sharing video after uploading on Vimeo?

Tags: vimeo-api

I was searching for API in Vimeo developer page. Is there any API by which we can share video through email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

After you've successfully uploaded a video via the API, you'll get a JSON response containing the vimeo code refering to the uploaded video. It'll be of the form "/vimeo/XXXXXXXX". The JSON should also contain the full links to your videos.

If you're not uploading the videos via the API, you can also just request a specific video via the "/me/videos" with a GET request. That should return relative information concerning 25-50 videos. If you have the video id (the XXXX part in the previous paragraph) then you can request information regarding one video via "/me/videos/XXXXXXXX/", which will contain all the links you'll need.

Once you have the links to your video(s), you can programatically send automatic emails to specific people.

If you're looking to share videos directly with the API to your followers, that is not possible I believe.

Let me know if you need more information.

*To be able to use the API you'll  have to create an app with the scopes you'll be using (upload, edit, etc) on the Vimeo Developper platform.*